# Remove object using linq

Tags: c#, linq

My objects are laid out where I have multiple relations in object Node. Relation object has a multiple rule objects

Is it possible to remove all objects at once instead of using first()? Actually I want to remove object rule if it exists in any of the relation objects

```
Node.relations.First().rules.Remove(rule);
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you taking about? What type is `relations` what type is `rules`? How is `Node` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

erm, you could use a loop. I'm assuming whatever type `rules` is supports `Contains`.

```
foreach(var relation in Node.relations)
{
    if (relation.rules.Contains(rule))
    {
        relation.rules.Remove(rule);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you´re looking after this?

```
var new relations = Node.relations.SelectMany(x => x.rules).Where(x => x != rule)
```

Select selects all rules within all relations that do NOT equal your given one.

EDIT: As GazTheDestroyer also mentioned LINQ is not designed for updating lists, but for querying them. So you either use LINQ for making a new list o create a list and call remove on its item as suggesed by GazTheDestroyer.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is inspired by functional programming, and as such is side-effect free. In other words linq queries do not alter data, only query it.

`Remove()` is not a linq method. It is a `List<T>` method. List also has a `ForEach()` method, so you could do:

```
Node.relations.ForEach(x => x.rules.Remove(rule));
```